# Как добавить запись в Fabric?

Tags: android

Для логирования отчетов об ошибках используется сервис Fabric Сrashlytics. Можно ли как-то к отчету добавить еще некоторую переменную, помимо отправки самого Exception?

В приложении есть переменная, которую нужно отправить вместе с ошибкой при возникновении бага.

Сrashlytics использую в классе Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crashlytics [позволяет добавить сообщение](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logging), которое будет прикреплено к следующему отчету с помощью метода `Crashlytics.log("blabla");`

Стоит учитывать, что все такие сообщения суммируются до тех пор, пока не произойдет падение и не будет отправлен отчет об ошибке.

Увидеть эти сообщения можно на экране всех сессий для конкретного отчета (кнопка "View all sessions").